# Render skeletal animated FBX 3d model on android

Tags: android, fbx, assimp, skeletal-animation

I am working on an android native project where there is a requirement to load animated fbx models on app, is there a way to achieve this.

Comment: You may want to try Open Asset Import Library (assimp) - https://github.com/assimp/assimp. It supports various file formats such as fbx. Here is also a blog post on how you could achieve this, http://www.anandmuralidhar.com/blog/android/assimp/

Comment: trying this app but getting this issue "Tool chain 'ndk-gcc' (GNU GCC): XCode arm-linux-androideabi-gcc is a wrapper around Clang. Treating it as Clang and not GCC. Stuck with this project compilation issue." unable to compile.

Comment: Resolved the GNU GCC by downgrading to ndk-12, but question still is open for skeletal animation.

Answer (score -1):

Skeletal animation are supported on the latest master for the FBX format. So just go for it. You can check this popular tutorial how to do this with assimp by using c: [Skeletal animation with assimp](http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/www/tutorial38/tutorial38.html)